# How to integrate linkedin login : Codeigniter

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have tried to integrate linkedin with my code.For this i have get the access of client_id and client_secret from linkedin developer account and put in this link like this

```
<a class="btn btn-linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id='<?php echo $this->config->item('Client_ID'); ?>'&redirect_uri='<?php echo $this->config->item('callback_url'); ?>'&state=98765EeFWf45A53sdfKef4233&scope=r_basicprofile r_emailaddress"><img src="./images/linkedin_connect_button.png" alt="Sign in with LinkedIn"/></a>
```

when i click on this link it will redirect to the page

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id='.$config['Client_ID'].'&redirect_uri='.$config['callback_url'].'&state=98765EeFWf45A53sdfKef4233&scope=r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
```

It's an error page from linkedin.
And one more thing i got this refrence from the link
https://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-linkedin-oauth2-in-php-and-mysql_3858.html

Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just delete the "' '" cause you putted the php in the html and not the html in the php like in the tuto , then your code will be like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=<?php echo $this->config->item('Client_ID'); ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo $this->config->item('callback_url'); ?>&state=98765EeFWf45A53sdfKef4233&scope=r_basicprofile r_emailaddress"><img src="./images/linkedin_connect_button.png" alt="Sign in with LinkedIn"/></a>
```